# R - spread & add rows

Tags: r, spread

I have long dataframe with this kind of data.

```
df <- read.table(text="
             category month  
1            1        2016-12 
2            1        2016-12 
3            1        2017-01 
4            5        2016-11 
5            5        2017-11 
6            4        2017-12", header=TRUE)
```

I need to spread that data by month and create for each category new row. For spreading I usually use spread function, but I don't know how to deal with that adding new rows.

Result should be

```
category    11-2016 12-2016 1-2017  11-2017 12-2017
1                 0       2      1        0       0
4                 0       0      0        0       1
5                 1       0      0        1       0
```

Comment: try with reshape2 package and use dcast u will get the desired one

Comment: don't you just need `table(df)` ?